# My html form and elements overlap and makes my page unintiutive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my form responsive with css because when I resize they overlap. I have tried dividing the pages using tables but it still does not work.

Here's my html and code:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>

    <header class="header">
    <h1 id="text" href="#a">Institutional Review Board  </h1> <h4 id="text">  Ashesi</h4>
  </header>


     <div class="div">
      <fieldset class="section"> 
       </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="section2">
           <h1 id="text" style="font-size: 40px;"> Welcome to the Ashesi IRB. </h1>

    <h2 id="text"> Sign In and Apply to Gain Permission to use Human Subjects In Your Research Work...</h2>
       </fieldset>
        </div>

        <form action='userlogin.php' method='GET'>

            <fieldset class="account-info">
                <label>
                    ID
                    <input type="text" name="id" required>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Password
                    <input type="password" name="password" required>
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="account-action">
                <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                <div class="change_link">
                Not a member yet?
                <a href="usersadd.php" >Join Now</a>
            </div>
            </fieldset> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my css code:

```
form {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
    border-rzadius: 5px;
    font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 70%; 
}
#text
{
color:white; 
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
display: inline;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
border:0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.header
{
text-align: left;
height= 400px;
background: linear-gradient(#CC0000 , #990000);
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #CCC;
margin:0px auto;
}

.div{
background-image: url("day.jpg"); 
height:570px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-attachment: fixed;

}

input {
border-radius: 5px;
font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
}

.section{
 padding :20px 20px 0 20px;
 font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 width: 500px;
 height:400px;
 background-color: #C0C0C0;
 border: 1px solid black;
 opacity: 0.5;
 float: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 15%;
 }
 .section2{
 padding :20px 20px 0 20px;
 font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 width: 500px;
 height:400px;
 float: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 15%;
}

.account-info {
 padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
 background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);

 }

.account-info label {
color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.account-info input {
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
 color: #636466;
 padding: 6px;
 margin-top: 6px;
 width: 100%;
}

.account-action {
background: #F8F8F8 ;
border-top: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
padding: 20px;
}


.account-action .btn {
background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
border: 0;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
padding: 8px 16px;
}

.account-action label {
color: #7c7c80;
font-size: 12spx;
float: left;
margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

.change_link{
color: #395870;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 1):

Here are my two cents for you.

Firstly, your css had a mistake while declaring height.

Here is the HTML

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <header class="header">
        <h1 id="text" href="#a">Institutional Review Board  </h1> <h4 id="text">Ashesi</h4>
</header>
</div>

<div class="div" style="position: relative;">
  <fieldset class="section"> 
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="section2">
   <h1 id="text" style="font-size: 40px;"> Welcome to the Ashesi IRB. </h1>

   <h2 id="text"> Sign In and Apply to Gain Permission to use Human Subjects In Your Research Work...</h2>
   </fieldset>
</div>

<div>
   <form action='userlogin.php' method='GET'>

    <fieldset class="account-info">
    <label>ID
        <input type="text" name="id" required>
    </label>
    <label>Password
        <input type="password" name="password" required>
    </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="account-action">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    <div class="change_link">
             Not a member yet?
        <a href="usersadd.php" >Join Now</a>
    </div>
</fieldset> 
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset {
padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
border: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.header {
text-align: left;
height: 100px;
background: linear-gradient(#CC0000, #990000);
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
margin: 0px auto;
}
.div {
background-image: url("day.jpg");
height: 570px;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
input {
border-radius: 5px;
font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
}
.section {
padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
background-color: #C0C0C0;
border: 1px solid black;
opacity: 0.5;
float: center;
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 15%;
}
.section2 {
padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
float: center;
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 15%;
}
.account-info {
padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
}
.account-info label {
color: #ffffff;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.account-info input {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
color: #636466;
padding: 6px;
margin-top: 6px;
width: 100%;
}
.account-action {
background: #F8F8F8;
border-top: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
padding: 20px;
}
.account-action .btn {
background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
border: 0;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
padding: 8px 16px;
}
.account-action label {
color: #7c7c80;
font-size: 12spx;
float: left;
margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}
.change_link {
color: #395870;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

The problem is that the position of your div is static, it is overriden by me to be relative, which makes more sense since you are going to be making it responsive.

I strongly recommend you to use something like bootstrap while you really want to make your website responsive.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'll do just that